# libva error: Cannot use VDPAU on nVidia 840M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, vdpau

I have a Primus laptop, and I cannot use VDPAU on Nvidia. I have installed Nvidia's proprietary driver from "Additional Drivers", but if I run "vainfo" in a terminal I get the error message:

```
imran@imran-PC:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.37.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_35
libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

If I run this on Intel HD Graphics then the output is fine. I cannot play 4K videos in [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) or [MPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) using VDPAU.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is Ubuntu version? Which drover did you install? Please add output of `prime-select query` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6, Output of "prime-select query" is "nvidia". I am using Ubuntu 15.04 with NVIDIA Proprietary driver version 340.76 from nvidia-340.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the driver

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo killall nvidia-persistenced
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346 nvidia-prime
```

Reboot.

Comment: Already installed :)

Comment: Updated the answer. 340 seems to be too old for 840M. @user294573

Comment: Ok, so i did installed nvidia-346 but still i am getting error if i type "vainfo" in terminal.